# Alternative to Python subprocess module in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, command-line, subprocess

I am currently attempting to migrate a python app to Google App Engine.  The application makes use of python's subprocess module to run a bash script that downloads a file from Google Cloud Storage, and then passes the file into an executable file.  I am aware that GAE does not allow writing of files and work with the file system, but is there any way I can do this or something similar on GAE?  Alternatives and other suggestions are very welcome.

Thank you,

Comment: What does the executable file do? Fetching the file can be performed with python code, but then it depends on what you want to do with the file.

Comment: The executable takes in a Debian package manifest, then returns a .dot file representing a graph of incompatible packages.  This is all based on the metadata in the Debian package manifest.

Answer (score 2):

GAE only runs python code.

Subprocess won't help you.  You can't run bash scripts in GAE.

You'll have to rewrite the bash script as a python program, at which point you probably just want to import and run your python script.